# ¿Cómo implementar Backpropagation through time a una red LSTM?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, redes-neuronales

Tengo implementada la red LSTM que muestro a continuación:

```
class IFOGates(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

  def __init__(self, nodes=768, input_shape=40):
      super(IFOGates, self).__init__()
      # Trainable variables
      self.Wix = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape, nodes), 
                                 initializer="random_normal", trainable=True, name="Wix")
      self.Wir = self.add_weight(shape=(nodes, nodes), 
                                 initializer="random_normal", trainable=True, name="Wir")
      self.Wic = self.add_weight(shape=(nodes, nodes), 
                                 initializer="random_normal", trainable=True, name="Wic")
      self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(1, nodes), 
                               initializer="random_normal", trainable=True, name="b")

  def call(self, inputs, rec_input, mem_input):  # Defines the computation from inputs to outputs
      return tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(inputs, self.Wix) + tf.matmul(rec_input, self.Wir) +\ 
                        tf.matmul(mem_input, self.Wic) + self.b)

class MemStateLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

  def __init__(self, nodes=12, input_shape=3):
    super(MemStateLayer, self).__init__()
    self.Wcx = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape, nodes), 
                               initializer="random_normal", trainable= True)
    self.Wcr = self.add_weight(shape=(nodes, nodes), 
                               initializer="random_normal", trainable= True)
    self.b = self.add_weight(shape=(1, nodes), trainable= True)

  def call(self, inputs, rec_input, forguet_state, mem_state, input_state):
    x = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(inputs, self.Wcx) + tf.matmul(rec_input, self.Wcr) + self.b)
    return tf.multiply(forguet_state, mem_state) + tf.multiply(input_state, x)

class WrapperLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, nodes = 768, projections=256, input_shape=3):
    super(WrapperLayer, self).__init__()

    self.projections = projections
    # Sublayers
    self.input_gate = IFOGates(nodes=nodes, 
                               input_shape=input_shape)
    self.forguet_gate = IFOGates(nodes=nodes, 
                               input_shape=input_shape)
    self.output_gate = IFOGates(nodes=nodes, 
                               input_shape=input_shape)
    self.mem_gate = MemStateLayer(nodes=nodes,
                               input_shape= input_shape)
    # Trainable variables
    self.Wrm = self.add_weight(shape=(nodes, nodes), 
                               initializer= "random_normal", trainable=True)
    self.Wpm = self.add_weight(shape=(nodes, projections), 
                               initializer= "random_normal", trainable=True)
    self.Wyr = self.add_weight(shape=(nodes, input_shape), 
                               initializer= "random_normal", trainable=True)
    self.Wyp = self.add_weight(shape=(projections, input_shape), 
                               initializer= "random_normal", trainable=True)
    self.b   = self.add_weight(shape=(1, input_shape), 
                               initializer= "random_normal", trainable=True)

    # Recursive information
    self.c_prev = self.add_weight(shape=(1, nodes), 
                                  initializer= "random_normal", trainable=False)
    self.r_prev = self.add_weight(shape=(1, nodes), 
                                  initializer= "random_normal", trainable=False)

  def call(self, input):
    i = self.input_gate(input, self.r_prev, self.c_prev)
    f = self.forguet_gate(input, self.r_prev, self.c_prev)
    c = self.mem_gate(input, self.r_prev, f, self.c_prev, i)
    o = self.output_gate(input, self.r_prev, c)
    m = tf.multiply(o, tf.tanh(c))
    r = tf.matmul(m, self.Wrm)
    p = tf.matmul(m, self.Wpm)
    # Update states for next step
    self.c_prev = c
    self.r_prev = r
    return tf.matmul(r, self.Wyr) + tf.matmul(p, self.Wyp) + self.b
```

Mi duda radica en como implementar la propagación hacia atrás a través del tiempo(BPTT).

En las búsquedas que he hecho encontré algo llamado BPTT truncada pero realmente no he sabido como interpretar el código en versiones anteriores de tensorflow ni cómo migrarlo a tensorflow2.5 que es la versión que uso y la que he estudiado.

Ésta es la primera vez que choco con tensorflow así que acepto cualquier crítica constructiva con respecto al código que muestro aquí.

Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: no he trabajado con redes LSTM, pero acaso estas no implementan eso?, ya que para tener memoria de lo antes hecho se debe de utilizar backpropagation ,o no?

Comment: Si, para entrenarlas se usa backpropagation. En la bibliografía hablan de BackpPropagation Through Time(BPTT). El dilema es que como ésta yo la implemento sin utilizar las capas LSTM de keras(que si vienen con todo implementado) no sé si al utilizar el gradiente respecto a las variables entrenables del modelo sea la forma correcta de implementar la BPTT.